# czmq: look for code example of "PUB/SUB + security"

Tags: ipc, zeromq

I am following this article: "http://hintjens.com/blog:49". The test code of "stonehouse" uses "PUSH/PULL" and I try to modify it to use "PUB/SUB". But my initial naive attempt fails (code below, which works for PUSH/PULL). Is there anything I miss? BTW, does czmq really work with PUB/SUB, because even I remove the lines related to security, it still doesn't work. Thank you for the help.

```
#include <czmq.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
//  Create context and start authentication engine
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
zauth_t *auth = zauth_new (ctx);
zauth_set_verbose (auth, true);
zauth_allow (auth, "127.0.0.1");

zauth_configure_curve (auth, "*", CURVE_ALLOW_ANY);

if (argc == 1)
{   zcert_t *server_cert = zcert_new ();
    char *server_key = zcert_public_txt (server_cert);
    printf ("%d: BEGIN '%s' END\n", strlen (server_key), server_key);

    void *server = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PUB/*PUSH*/);
    zcert_apply (server_cert, server);
    zsocket_set_curve_server (server, 1);
    zsocket_bind (server, "tcp://*:9000");
    printf ("Hit any key to start sending...\n");
    getchar ();
    int i=5;
    while (i > 0)
    {   printf ("%d ", i); fflush (stdout);
        sleep (1);
        --i;
    }
    zstr_send (server, "Hello");
    printf ("sent\n");
    zcert_destroy (&server_cert);
}
else
{   zcert_t *client_cert = zcert_new ();

    void *client = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_SUB/*PULL*/);
    zcert_apply (client_cert, client);
    zsocket_set_curve_serverkey (client, argv[1]);
    zsocket_connect (client, "tcp://127.0.0.1:9000");

    char *message = zstr_recv (client);
    printf ("received: %s\n", message);
    assert (streq (message, "Hello"));
    free (message);
    puts ("Stonehouse test OK");

    zcert_destroy (&client_cert);
}

zauth_destroy (&auth);
zctx_destroy (&ctx);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out: the subscriber needs to set the option of "ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE". Otherwise, it receives nothing. I previously assume the opposite, which is wrong.